# jquery event handler called many times

Tags: jquery, events

Register a click event as following, when clicking an empty space once in a page, the handler is called 5 times. I expected it to be called once.

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
        console.log(event.target);
    });
```

Could anyone explain this? Thanks.

Comment: Does that piece of code reproduce your problem? If not, can you provide us with a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that does?

Comment: Cannot reproduce it from your code snippet

Comment: This question is unanswerable (other than wild guesses) without more info as the three lines of code by themselves will not cause this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be loading you're code 5 times. How did you include it on your page ? (edit your question to answer)

Comment: Though this is a guess, it seems like a plausible guess.

Comment: I place my bet on framework assets with code included in multiple files.

Comment: It may be registered multiple times. Everytime ajax update an element, the event is registered. I should use $(document).off(click, func) to remove previous registered handlers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `.click()` eventHandler sets a new event handler on each click (instead of replacing - like you're expecting.)

You should be able to resolve this by unbinding, then rebinding the event handler:

```
$(document).unbind('click').click(function(event) {
//...//
});
```

**[EDIT]**

The `.unbind()` event handler is depreciated... so the above should be this:

```
$(document).off('click').on('click', function(event) {
// do things //
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```js
$(document).on('click', function(e){
  console.log(e.target);  
});
```

Comment: This is no different than the OP's code.  `.click(...)` is just an alias for `.on("click", ...)`.